# Getting invalid grant while fetching access token from Google Oauth

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-oauth

I know this question asked many times but currently we have a problem with fetching access token from Google Oauth. Actually, "sign in with Google" works for some accounts on the other hand it doesn't work for some accounts. So we couldn't catch the exact problem.

Actually, there is no problem with fetching code from googleapis...auth?... -> return code.

But fetching access token returns error:

```
https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token?code=4/0AY0...
&client_id=....apps.googleusercontent.com
&client_secret=...
&redirect_uri=...
&grant_type=authorization_code
```

Some cases we encounter with:

```
{
    "error": "invalid_grant",
    "error_description": "Bad Request"
}
```

Any suggestion?

Note: I did some research, but none of the suggestions helped (spelling, checking server time, adding access_type=offline to the first OAuth step url, etc.)

**Solution:**

When I try to fetch token with same code multiple time, google throws `invalid_grant` error.

```
1. call https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token?code=my_code -> returns OK.
2. call same request again https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token?code=my_code -> returns invalid_grant.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you try to fetch token with same code multiple time, google throws invalid_grant error.

```
1. call https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token?code=my_code -> returns OK.
2. call same request again https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token?code=my_code -> returns invalid_grant.
```